# Showing that $P(x)$, where $P(x) = P(x+2)-x^2-2$ for all $x$, is a third-degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I want to show that $P(x)$ is a third degree polymomial:
$P(x) = P(x+2) -x^2-2$  for every real $x$

It is not so difficult, but I am not seeing the proof straight away.

Comment: check what happens to the degree when in any polynomial $P(x)$ you let $x=x+2$ then consider what @GitGud said above to look at $P(x+2)-P(x)$ which is a rearrangement of what you were given

Comment: @Jepsilon I've removed my hint because I realised I can't deal with a detail that comes up.

Comment: @GitGud Was your detail something regarding the differentiability of $P$ itself?

Comment: @String Precisely!

Comment: Wait why use differentiability? Just try out a couple of polynomials of different degrees with the substitution $x=x+2$ (or $x=x+a$ to be a bit more general) and compare the degrees from before and after the transformation.

Comment: @Jepsilon again assuming $P$ is a polynomial. Which is already assuming differentiability and some more.

Comment: Wait so you were given no info about $P$? I thought it was "here's a polynomial show that its degree is 3 given...". I guess I misread the question apologies

Answer (score 6):

For any polynomial with degree $n$ and for each constant $k\neq0$, $P(x+k)-P(x)$ is a polynomial whose degree is $n-1$; to see why, just expand $P(x+k)$.

Since, in your case, $P(x+2)-P(x)$ has degree $2$, $P(x)$ is a cubic polynomial.

Note that this assumes that $P(x)$ is a polynomial function. Otherwise, the statement is false. A counter-example is this:$$P(x)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{4 x}{3}&\text{ if $x$ is algebraic}\\[3mm]\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{4 x}{3}+1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $P$ is $C^3$, you have $P'''(x) = P'''(x+2)$ for all $x$.  Since $P'''$ is continuous, we conclude that it's constant.  When we integrate 3 times, we get a cubic polynomial.

Comment: Can you make this argument work with the third differences rather than the third derivative, so that you can avoid assuming differentiability? You may need to assume continuity.

Answer (score 2):

The statement, as written, is false.

Take **any** function on $[0,2]$ with $p(2)=p(0)+2$. The linear function $p(x) = x$ between 0 and 2 will do. Again, it linear on this domain. Now use the relations $p(x+2) = p(x)+x^2+2$ to determine the function of $[2,4]$ then on $[4,6]$, etc. and $p(x-2)=p(x)-x^2-2$ on $[-2,0]$, $[-4,-2]$, etc.

For example, between $[2,4]$, 
$$p(x)=p(x-2)+x^2-4x+6=(x-2)+x^2-4x+6$$
So you have a piece-wise continuous function that satisfies the criterion but is linear on $[0,2]$ and second degree on other intervals.

Obviously, you can take any nasty function you want on $[0,2]$ that satisfies $p(2)=p(0)+2$ and get a non-polynomial solution of the recurrence relation.

Now, if one assumes that $p(x)$ is a polynomial, I don't think you can do it in any way other than simply assuming
$$p(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0.$$
Then use the binomial theorem to expand $p(x+2)$ then subtract $p(x)$ and set it equal to $x^2+2$. You will get $a_n =a_{n-1} =\cdots = a_4 = 0$ and $6a_3=1$, $12a_3+4a_2=0$ and $8a_3+4a_2+2a_1=2$ and $a_0$ arbitrary.

Final answer: $p(x)=\frac16x^3-\frac12x^2+\frac{13}3x+C$

Comment: I don't have maple on this computer, so my arithmetic might be faulty!

Answer (score 0):

Let:
$$\begin{align}P(x+2)&=a_0(x+2)^n+a_1(x+2)^{n-1}+a_2(x+2)^{n-2}+\cdots+a_n\\
P(x)&=\color{red}{a_0}x^n+\color{blue}{a_1}x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_n \\
x^2+2=P(x+2)-P(x)&=2na_0x^{n-1}+(2n(n-1)a_0+2(n-1)a_1)x^{n-2}+\cdots \Rightarrow \\
x^2&=2na_0x^{n-1} \Rightarrow \\
2&=n-1 \quad \text{and} \quad 2na_0=1\Rightarrow \\
n&=3 \quad \text{and} \quad \color{red}{a_0}=\frac16. \end{align}$$
Thus $n=3$. You can continue to find the next coefficient:
$$2n(n-1)a_0+2(n-1)a_1=0 \Rightarrow \color{blue}{a_1}=\frac{-2}{4}=-\frac12.$$